# Google API account for application, pemanent token

Tags: oauth, google-api

Goal: save data from application to Google Drive - there is separated google account that represents the app and I want data to be saved there, not in user's drives

Question: How to create permanent token for my app that can work w/o additional autentification?

If I understand the api correctly you create token and it can expire after 25 refreshs. That would cause the app to stop working and someone with access to google account of the application would have to reauthorize it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create
[service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount).